# Serializing an unmapped property in JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to understand whether it's possible to have an unmapped property in a JPA entity and also have it serialize. I want to do this because I'd like to query rows from my database, then do calculations on a few of those returned fields and populate the result in one of the unmapped fields. However, the only solution I've seen to adding an unmapped property within an entity is to use the @Transient annotation, which means the property will not serialize.

Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: The `@Transient` annotation is only for JPA. If you serialize an object, the attribute will be serialized normally (unless it's has the `transient` **modifier**). So do use the @Transient annotation, as that's the right way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: Adding @Transient from javax.persistence actually does not serialize it for me.

Comment: How do you know that it doesn`t serialize it?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Did one of the answers help you? Please remember to come back and accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: Actually none of the answers helped. I've instead just accepted creating a new POJO that I transfer the needed attributes over to once they are populated from the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Fields with **@Transient** annotation it should be serialize using the Java serialization api, check if you have the modifier **transient**, this modifier won’t allow you to serialize this field.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect Rigre Garciandía's answer to work (i.e. use @Transient), but...

You could implement externalizable. It gives you complete control over serialization and deserialization, so you can write and read any fields you like (and can improve performance as a side benefit in my experience):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html